# Why so many files to delete? Warning: 112681 files will be deleted in

Tags: cloudberry

I'm playing with CBB and am impressed so far.

I have been trying out running local backups to an external disk. Following the last run I have got a message on the welcome tab of CB.

> Warning: 112681 files will be deleted in 89 days

90 days being the retention I have set on locally deleted files.

This accounts for all the files I have in the backup source location, plus some recent movements of files around a bit (which I guess are treated as deleted files in old locations, and new files in new locations - hence duplication).

Looking at the list, it seems to be intending to delete all the files in the backup.

What is odd is that in the list of "Files to Delete" dialog. All the file names have `:ad` appended to their filenames, for example, `textfile.text:ad`.

It's as if CBB thinks that the files have changed or been replaced, but the majority of files have not changed in any way, location, permissions, attributes, etc. So why does CBB think these files need deleting from the backup?

Q1) Anyone have any idea why this might be the case?

Q2) What is the `:ad`? and what does it mean?

I'm slightly concerned about the opacity of CBB and want to be sure that backups are OK before I ditch the more manual [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) scripts I currently use.

Comment: How is this question programming related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This happen because you set additional retention policy in the plan configuration - "Retention step" and "Delete files that have been deleted locally". This actually called "Smart delete" and it purges data from your backup destination (e.g. block storage or cloud). Please check you configuration.

2) :ad mark actually flags your objects (files) to purge in 89 days.

Comment: You're totaly right. I did change the retention after the I completed a backup run. So, is it right to assume that until the retention expires, there will duplicate copies on the drive?

Answer (score 0):

It is called differently right now (5.1), but the idea is exactly as written above.